# Error installing cakephp/localized via Composer, conflicts with cakephp/chronos and cakephp/database

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

I tried to install cakephp/localized using the following commands:

```
composer require cakephp/localized
```

or:

```
composer.phar require --update-with-dependencies "cakephp/localized"
```

And gives the following error:

```
$ composer.phar require --update-with-dependencies -W "cakephp/localized"
Using version ^3.5 for cakephp/localized
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update cakephp/localized --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - cakephp/localized[3.5.0, ..., 3.5.2] require cakephp/cakephp ^3.5 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.5.0, ..., 3.10.0].
    - cakephp/cakephp[3.5.0, ..., 3.5.14] require cakephp/chronos ^1.0.0 -> found cakephp/chronos[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2).
    - cakephp/cakephp[3.5.15, ..., 3.10.0] require cakephp/chronos ^1.0.1 -> found cakephp/chronos[1.0.1, ..., 1.3.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2).
    - Root composer.json requires cakephp/localized ^3.5 -> satisfiable by cakephp/localized[3.5.0, 3.5.1, 3.5.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

If I manually enter cakephp/localized no in composer.json file and give composer.update command, it conflicts with cakephp/database:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires selective/array-reader ^1.1 -> satisfiable by selective/array-reader[1.1.0].
    - selective/array-reader 1.1.0 requires cakephp/chronos ^2 -> found cakephp/chronos[2.0.0, ..., 2.2.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^1).
  Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires cakephp/localized 3.5.2 -> satisfiable by cakephp/localized[3.5.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.0.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.0.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.0.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.0.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.0.7 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.0.8 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.0.9 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.1.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.1.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.1.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.1.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.1.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.1.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.1.7 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.2.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.2.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.2.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.2.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.2.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.2.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.2.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.2.7 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install cakephp/database 4.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - cakephp/localized 3.5.2 requires cakephp/cakephp ^3.5 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.5.0, ..., 3.10.0].
    - Only one of these can be installed: cakephp/cakephp[3.5.0, ..., 3.10.0], cakephp/database[4.0.0, ..., 4.2.7]. cakephp/cakephp replaces cakephp/database and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires cakephp/database ^4 -> satisfiable by cakephp/database[4.0.0, ..., 4.2.7].
```

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

The following dependencies are in my composer.json file:

```
"cakephp/chronos": "^2",
"cakephp/database": "^4",
"cakephp/validation": "^4.2",
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the 4.x version of cakephp/localized

Answer (score -1):

The error message is pretty clear:

```
  Problem 1
    - cakephp/localized[3.5.0, ..., 3.5.2] require cakephp/cakephp ^3.5 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.5.0, ..., 3.10.0].
    - cakephp/cakephp[3.5.0, ..., 3.5.14] require cakephp/chronos ^1.0.0 -> found cakephp/chronos[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2).
```

You want to install a package that requires `cakephp/chronos` v1, but you already require `cakephp/chronos` v2. Either downgrade the package to v1 in your own composer.json, or search for an updated version of the other package that supports `cakephp/chronos` v2